# Visual Studio: Setting Textbox Width, given a MONSPACED font and a MaxLength

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, fonts

I'm using visual studio 2013 for a forms app.

For short data entry fields such as "First Name", I like to use monospaced fonts in textboxes whose width is just sufficient for the number of characters allowed.  (MaxLength property)  That way the user can see visually how many characters are allowed.

BUT... My latest front end allows the user to "zoom in or out" for different screen resolutions and visibility.  So to accomplish the same result, I have to change the width of textboxes based on font size.

I would have thought MeasureString would be the answer, (with some added width to accommodate the text cursor and border) but I'm getting mixed results.  I understand one of the problems with MeasureString is that it's designed to accommodate kerning. ... But that's why I'm using a monospaced font.  Kerning shouldn't matter as far as I know.

All I need is a function which, given a MONOSPACED font, returns the width of a single character in pixels.  Sounds easier than it's turning out to be.

Any guidance?

Comment: MeasureString is almost never the answer.  To measure text for a TextBox you have to use TextRenderer.MeasureText().  And deal with its knack for adding glyph overhang elbow room, the longer the string the more accurate it gets.

Comment: Thank you.  I was thinking whatever approach I'd use, I could compare the width of "01234567890" to the width of "00", which should be exactly the width of 9 characters without whatever it adds at either end.  (Then divide by 9.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is "an answer", because for me it seems to work best, but I wouldn't call it "the correct answer" because it's a little code-intensive.  I have been disappointed with all of the following:

```
Graphics.MeasureString()
TextRenderer.MeaureText()
Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges()
```

And I've experimented with CompositingQuality, TextRenderingHint, and SmoothingMode until I'm blue in the face.  None of these approaches seem to produce consistent results for different font sizes, units, and ***importantly***, a user's Windows Display setting for Small, Medium, or Large text.

It seems to me the problem is all of these methods use "drawn" text to ***estimate*** the width of text, but text rendered in a control isn't done the same way.  So if that's true, using drawn text to estimate the width of text in a control can never work perfectly.  I would have assumed Microsoft would provide something to do this easily ***and perfectly***, and I may be wrong but from what I'm observing, Microsoft hasn't gotten it right yet.

Below is code that I found works very accurately regardless of windows settings, font units, or anything having to do with a graphics object.  It creates an invisible multiline TextBox, then shrinks its Width property one pixel at a time until it forces the text to wrap, taking note of the resulting width.

To use this code:

- Use a monospaced font in your TextBoxes and ComboBoxes.  I use Lucida Console which looks good and accommodates any version of Windows still supported.
- Call ResizeControlForFont to resize a TextBox or ComboBox appropriately for its preset font.
- Call SetFontSizeAndResizeControl if you want to adjust the font size and width of the control in one step.

.

```
Public Sub ResizeControlForFont(ByVal Cont As Control, Optional ByVal WidthInCharacters As Integer = 0)
    'This for single or multiline textboxes and comboboxes.
    'A MONOSPACED font must first be assigned to the control before calling this. 
    'If you prefer to do it in a single step, call SetFontSizeAndResizeControl, which will call this procedure.
    'If WidthInCharacters is not specified, it will use the MaxLength property of the control, if possible.
    'For multiline textboxes, ALWAYS specify the number of columns desired when calling this procedure. You don't want to use the MaxLength property of a multiline textbox.
    Dim CharacterWidth As Single = GetWidthOfCharacter(Cont.Font)
    Dim AddedWidth As Integer = (CharacterWidth * 0.3) + 2 'I've chosen 30% of a character's width plus 2 pixels and I like the results.
    'If not supplied, use the MaxLength property if available and appropriate.
    If WidthInCharacters = 0 Then
        If TypeOf Cont Is TextBox Then
            Dim tmpItem As TextBox = Cont
            If tmpItem.Multiline = False Then
                'Don't do this for multiline textboxes.
                WidthInCharacters = tmpItem.MaxLength
            End If
        ElseIf TypeOf Cont Is ComboBox Then
            Dim tmpItem As ComboBox = Cont
            WidthInCharacters = tmpItem.MaxLength
        End If
    End If
    If TypeOf Cont Is TextBox Then
        'For multiline textboxes, Always specify the number of columns desired.
        Dim tmpItem As TextBox = Cont
        If tmpItem.Multiline = True Then
            'Only do this for multiline textboxes.
            AddedWidth = AddedWidth + SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth
        End If
    ElseIf TypeOf Cont Is ComboBox Then
        Dim tmpItem As ComboBox = Cont
        AddedWidth = AddedWidth + SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth
    End If
    Cont.Width = (WidthInCharacters * CharacterWidth) + AddedWidth

End Sub

Public Sub SetFontSizeAndResizeControl(ByVal Cont As Control, ByVal NewFontSize As Single, Optional ByVal WidthInCharacters As Integer = 0)
    'Sets the font size and resizes it in one step.
    Cont.Font = New Font(Cont.Font.Name, NewFontSize, Cont.Font.Style, Cont.Font.Unit, Cont.Font.GdiCharSet, Cont.Font.GdiVerticalFont)
    Call ResizeControlForFont(Cont, WidthInCharacters)
End Sub

Public Function GetWidthOfCharacter(ByVal CtrlFont As Font) As Single
    Static LastResult As Single
    Static LastCtrlFont As Font
    'OPTIMIZING.  Don't repeat what you don't have to.
    'Sending the same font to this function twice in a row will skip the test and return the last result.
    'To take advantage of this, resize all controls with the same font and size all together.
    If Not LastCtrlFont Is Nothing Then
        If CtrlFont.Name = LastCtrlFont.Name And CtrlFont.Size = LastCtrlFont.Size And CtrlFont.Style = LastCtrlFont.Style And CtrlFont.GdiCharSet = LastCtrlFont.GdiCharSet And CtrlFont.GdiVerticalFont = LastCtrlFont.GdiVerticalFont Then
            Return LastResult 'Speeds things up if the same font was used last time.  Useful when sizing many controls with the same font.
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    Dim TinyString As String = StrDup(51, "W") 'Two strings of aribitrary length, ample for the precision we need.
    Dim BigString As String = StrDup(99, "W") '
    Dim tmpTxt As New TextBox 'Temporarily created textbox.
    With tmpTxt
        .Font = CtrlFont
        .Height = .Height * 2.5 'Just ensures it's tall enough to work.
        .Multiline = True
        .ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical
        .Font = CtrlFont

        'Do this twice.  First with TinyString.
        .Width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(TinyString, CtrlFont).Width + SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth 'Start by making it a little too big using MeasureText
        .Text = TinyString
        Do Until .GetLineFromCharIndex(.TextLength) > 0 Or .Width = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth
            .Width = .Width - 1
        Loop
        Dim TinyWidth As Integer = .Width

        'Do it again with BigString.
        .Width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(BigString, CtrlFont).Width + SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth 'Start by making it a little too big using MeasureText
        .Text = BigString
        Do Until .GetLineFromCharIndex(.TextLength) > 0 Or .Width = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth
            .Width = .Width - 1
        Loop
        Dim BigWidth As Integer = .Width

        'We did it twice to isolate the width of characters from width added by padding, borders and the scrollbar.
        'We compare the two results, leaving only a difference in width created by the characters themselves.
        'The Denominator here is the difference in the number of characters.
        LastResult = (BigWidth - TinyWidth) / (Len(BigString) - Len(TinyString))

        LastCtrlFont = CtrlFont 'Remember this so we can skip it if we try the same font again next time
        Return LastResult
    End With
End Function
```

Is it the right approach?  Well, it's a bit code-intensive.  But it's the only approach I've found that produces exactly correct and consistent results.  If Microsoft has a better way, I'm open to it.  But I've been disappointed with     ***Graphics.MeasureString()***, ***TextRenderer.MeaureText()***, and ***Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges()***

Although I started this for single-line textboxes, it can be used with ComboBoxes and also multiline TextBoxes, where it will add width for the dropdown button or vertical scrollbar.  In the latter case, you'll want to pass the desired number of columns.  In all cases it uses the MaxLength property of the control if you don't furnish a width in characters.  (Which is bad for a multiline textbox.)

To use this code in the most optimal way, all controls with the same font size should be passed through it together so it will skip unnecessary calculations and textbox rendering.